# What is expected as argument for this method?

Tags: c#, methods, arguments, rhino3d

I am trying to use the `DivideByLength` method below based on the [RhinoCommon](http://www.rhino3d.com/5/rhinocommon/html/M_Rhino_Geometry_Curve_DivideByLength_1.htm) SDK but I cannot understand what the third argument is. I have tried to write the code below based on this method but I get the following error message: `Error: 'Rhino.Geometry.Point3d' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`

I thought the third argument was to specify that I wanted points as output and not doubles. What am I doing wrong?

Method:

```
Public Function DivideByLength ( _
    segmentLength As Double, _
    includeStart As Boolean, _
    <OutAttribute> ByRef points As Point3d() _
) As Double()
```

Code:

```
List<Point3d> pts = new List<Point3d>();

for(int i = 0; i < crv.Count;i = i + 2)
{
  pts.Add(crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true, out Point3d()));
}
```

Comment: You have to specify a variable next to the out keyword. More here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you're after. Your `out` parameter is an array of `Point3d` objects and it looks like you want to get a list of all of the ones in all of the returned arrays. So you'd have your list, and need to `AddRange` the results.

```
List<Point3d> pts = new List<Point3d>();

for(int i = 0; i < crv.Count;i = i + 2)
{
    Point3d[] arr;
    crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true, out arr);
    pts.AddRange(arr);
}
```

Comment: For the record, it's easy enough to flatten a `List<Point3d[]>` if that's what's needed.  +1 for the good observation though.

Comment: @Servy Good point (pun intended). The `List<Point3d[]>` may be the better option, so you get the choice later on whether you want to flatten or not.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like this is what you're looking for:

```
List<Point3d[]> pts = new List<Point3d[]>();

for(int i = 0; i < crv.Count;i = i + 2)
{
  Point3d[] pointArray;
  crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true, out pointArray);
  pts.Add(pointArray);
}
```

See the [out parameter documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I just caught that (my unfamiliarity with VB caused me to glance over it at first).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use in c#:

```
List<Point3d[]> ptlist = new List<Point3d[]>();
    Point3d[] pts;

    for(int i = 0; i < crv.Count;i = i + 2)
    {
       crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true, out pts);
       ptlist.add(pts);
    }
```

Using new is not wrong but useless since is the function returning the array as an output.

Answer (score 1):

You need `new Point3d()` instead of `Point3d()` you need to instanstiate the Point3d instead of passing Point3d

```
Point3d objPoint3d = new Point3d();

pts.Add(crv[i].DivideByLength(nb, true, out objPoint3d));
```

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the variable. The `out` clause means the variable will be instantiated inside the method. Plus it's an array, not a single instance of `Point3d`, so it would be `Point3d[]`.